# Powershell with Robocopy and CSV files

Tags: powershell, csv, robocopy

So I am pretty green at powershell, and I have looked around for similar issues but can't seem to find out what my issue is. My CSV has usernames from active directory in it, and would work if the `@{user= }` wasn't there. I was pleased with myself for getting this far, but it seems I can't quite push it over the finish line. Please help StackOverFlow users!

```
$csvFile = 'C:\scripts\HomeDirectory\CN\CN-homedirectory.csv'
$SrcHome = '\\ch-hz-usrhome1\e$\Home\'
$DstHome = '\\us-svr-bk2\d$\files\CN_Files\'

  Import-Csv $csvFile -Delimiter ";" | ForEach-Object {
   $srcDoc = "$("$SrcHome$_.User")"
   $dstDoc = "$("$DstHome$_.User\UsersHomeDrive")"

    RoboCopy $srcDoc $dstDoc /Z /SEC /MIR /COPY:DAT /r:10 /w:40 /log+:C:\scripts\HomeDirectory\CN\CN_UserData.log
  }
```

When I look at the log file, I see the following:

```
Source : \\ch-hz-usrhome1\e$\Home\@{User=xyu}.User\
Dest : \\us-svr-bk2\d$\files\CN_Files\@{User=xyu}.User\UsersHomeDrive\
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a property of an object to be expanded in a string, you need to use the [*subexpression operator*](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-operators.html) `$()`.

A better way to build paths is to use `Join-Path`:

```
$srcDoc = Join-Path $SrcHome $_.User
$dstDoc = Join-Path $DstHome (Join-Path $_.User "UsersHomeDrive")
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I feel like an idiot it being so simple to fix. its appreaciated!